# How can I calculate how many Corruption Points I should give to each party member in a given situation?

Tags: dark-heresy-1e, corruption

I am currently GMing a campaign where, in one particular session, the party found a book that describes dark rituals, interrupted a summoning ritual and encountered some Horrors.

I'm new to the concept of awarding Corruption Points, and I'm not sure how many I should be giving out based on the above events.

I know that close encounters with the warp gives you corruption, but how can I calculate the amount of Corruption Points I should give to each party member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the actual detail of the encounters the party have had and their reactions, I would give 1 Corruption Point (CP) to any given Party Member if they had:

- Attempted to read any of the book
- Looked into a warp portal as part of the summoning ritual for any meaningful amount of time (i.e. specifically looked at the portal as an action/said "I'll look into the portal")
- Got into close combat with the Horrors for more than one round

From this, I'd award between 1-3 CP.

Bear in mind that you may have other aspects in your particular situation that you haven't elaborated on (i.e. "encountered a book" doesn't detail *what actually happened*; did the interruption of the ritual coincide with fighting the Horrors, or were they separate situations? How many Horrors were there?), and could lead to more CP; you could also run a harder campaign and assign a random amount of CP (D5-2/D3/D5).

Comment: Thank you, for the help. What happened was that they interrupted the summoning process and only 3 Horrors managed to enter. Their fight was 6 rounds through which they were in close proximity to the horrors.

Comment: If this has answered your question, it would be beneficial if you could mark it as answered by clicking the empty "tick" to the left of the answer.